# JMeter aggregate report malfunctioning

Tags: testing, jmeter

Did anybody encounter an incorrect report? I set up a web test plan following the tutorial http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html, except that I added a CSV Data Set Config to read request parameters from a file. The test process finished without warning, but the data in the aggerate report is weird.

It gives something like this:
[image: jmeter result]

However according to the document http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report,

```
Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time in secs)
           = 1000 * (number of requests) / (total time in millionsec)
Average = (total time in millionsec) / (number of requests)
```

which means `Average * Throughput` should almost be `1000`.

What's wrong with my report?

ps: the formula above come from http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html#Throughput

Comment: I don't think this is a question with an obvious answer, the document escape most details of how they calculate these numbers and how we can validate them. And I don't think it's appropriate to down vote others question without a word to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Well start from the beginning: if you run 1 thread, 1 iteration, and that sampler completes in 1001 ms, your throughput will be 1000 ms / 1001 ms = 1/sec.

Now say you add one more thread, and they both start right away (still running for 1 iteration). Say, average remains the same. So throughput will be 2 * (1000 ms / 1001 ms) = 2/sec (in other words: 2 samplers finished within 1 sec)

Now let's add iterations: 2 threads, 2 iterations, same average: in first second throughput will be same as before 2/sec, and on 2nd second throughput will be same as before 2/sec, so still about 2/sec on average

But now let's add a ramp-up period 1 second: first thread starts immediately, while the second starts after 500 ms; same average. So on the first second throughput will be 1/sec (second thread will not complete first iteration yet, since it started later); 2nd second the throughput will be 2/sec (second iteration for first thread, first iteration for the second); on 3rd second, thread 1 finished, but second still in the middle of second iteration, so throughput will be 1/sec. Thus average throughput = (1/sec + 2/sec + 1/sec) / 3 sec. = 4/3 sec. = 1.3/sec

And so on - pretty boring until you get to *saturation point*. Before saturation point the more you give to server, the better/bigger throughput is. After saturation point, even if server has more work, it won't be able to improve throughput.

For example say I only can send 1 request at the time to my server. So even though I have 2 threads, throughput would be 1/sec in above examples.

So your screenshot shows 4000 samples 229 ms average and 56.8/sec throughput. If you had 1 user running 4000 iterations sequentially, you'd have a throughput of 1000 / 229 ms = 4.4/sec, so you have more than 1 user; 56.8/sec throughput means about 16 users in fact. How many exactly I cannot tell, since I don't know your ramp-up time and whether you are before or after saturation point. For example you may have 100 concurrent users, but in reality only about 16 simultaneous connections are established to the server (past saturation point), or maybe you've made a slow ramp up, which means by the time user #17 starts, user #1 is already done. So even though server could handle more, it never gets a chance.

Oh, and it can also be less than 16 concurrent users: I am judging from average throughput, which is a good indicator in most cases, but not always: it could be affected by a particularly high or low throughput at some period of time. For example, at first throughput was 1/sec and then when server ramped up, it became 100/sec. Average is 50/sec, but that last number - 50/sec is meaningless. It would be more valuable to see how the value changed over time.

Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, and I unserstand your point. I set the thread num to 20, ramp-up Period to 0(I want send 20 requests at the same time ), iterate for 200 times. The logic in the apllication I test on can't handle request in a concurrent or parallel way, so I think the throughput for one user and for 16 users  should be exactly the same. I want to test how the qps will change after I change the logic to concurrent.